# Decode from base64 - understand results

Tags: javascript, base64, decode

I would like to know what means the "s" parameters on a decode base64 results, as the follow example:

```
{s:5:"popup";a:9:{s:2:"id";s:2:"34";{s:20:'publish_key';s:36:'abc';s:10:'theme';s:6:'summer';s:13:'reminder';s:4:'2000';s:12:'merge';s:2:'on';s:8:'timezone';s:15:'America/Toronto';  (...)
```

So what stands for `s:20, s:36, s:10` (etc.) and `a:9`?

Comment: Decoded base64 returns whatever was base64 encoded in the first place. You'd need to set some breakpoints in your console and observe how the data is used or ask the person who encoded it

Comment: Thank you @andrew, I did find the solution, it is a serialized code and can be unserialized with online tools, as this: http://www.unserialize.com/